# Quickbooks OAuth identify user of callback using state - Is this good practice and are there any security concerns?

Tags: oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm working on an application using OAuth2.0 for Quickbooks. I'm basing my code on the [example provided by intuit](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2.0-demo-nodejs). Here I have looked a bit on the "state" parameter of the oauthClient.authorizeUri.

```
oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
    clientId: req.query.json.clientId,
    clientSecret: req.query.json.clientSecret,
    environment: req.query.json.environment,
    redirectUri: req.query.json.redirectUri,
  });
  OAuthClient;
  var authUri = oauthClient.authorizeUri({
    scope: [OAuthClient.scopes.Accounting],
    state: "userid:1234", //Encoded as a JWT 
  });
  res.send(authUri);
});
```

I was thinking of encoding an internal user- and projectid in the state through a JWT only for this purpose. I need it for the callback to make sure that I'm connecting the right internal user with the QB token.

I have two questions here:

Is it "safe" to encode an internal userid in the "state" like that? Or is there a better way of doing what I want? I'm working with a distributed service (GCP CloudRun), so it might not be the same instance receiving the callback as the one that created the authUri.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert here, but a read of the spec seems to indicate this should *not* be a guessable value like `user_id` would be.

From the spec ( https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#page-26 ):

```
state
         RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
         state between the request and callback.  The authorization
         server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
         to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
         cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.
```

and:

```
10.12.  Cross-Site Request Forgery

   Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) is an exploit in which an attacker
   causes the user-agent of a victim end-user to follow a malicious URI
   (e.g., provided to the user-agent as a misleading link, image, or
   redirection) to a trusting server (usually established via the
   presence of a valid session cookie).

   A CSRF attack against the client's redirection URI allows an attacker
   to inject its own authorization code or access token, which can
   result in the client using an access token associated with the
   attacker's protected resources rather than the victim's (e.g., save
   the victim's bank account information to a protected resource
   controlled by the attacker).

   The client MUST implement CSRF protection for its redirection URI.
   This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the
   redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to
   the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session
   cookie used to authenticate the user-agent).  The client SHOULD
   utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the
   authorization server when making an authorization request.

   Once authorization has been obtained from the end-user, the
   authorization server redirects the end-user's user-agent back to the
   client with the required binding value contained in the "state"
   parameter.  The binding value enables the client to verify the
   validity of the request by matching the binding value to the
   user-agent's authenticated state.  The binding value used for CSRF
   protection MUST contain a non-guessable value (as described in
   Section 10.10), and the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g.,
   session cookie, HTML5 local storage) MUST be kept in a location
   accessible only to the client and the user-agent (i.e., protected by
   same-origin policy).

   A CSRF attack against the authorization server's authorization
   endpoint can result in an attacker obtaining end-user authorization
   for a malicious client without involving or alerting the end-user.

   The authorization server MUST implement CSRF protection for its
   authorization endpoint and ensure that a malicious client cannot
   obtain authorization without the awareness and explicit consent of
   the resource owner.
```

Given that the spec recommends the `state` parameter be used for CSRF protection, and that the `user_id` is going to be easily guessable (i.e. the opposite of what you'd want for CSRF protection) it doesn't seem like a good idea to be putting the `user_id` into the `state` parameter.

Some other sources seem to confirm this:

- https://auth0.com/docs/secure/attack-protection/state-parameters
- https://medium.com/keycloak/the-importance-of-the-state-parameter-in-oauth-5419c94bef4c

Comment: Thanks for the response. Read a little more into it and asked the staff at Quickbooks. It should be used to connect the callback information with the initial request which is what I wanted to do. The CSRF protection should be fine since the user_id is going to be encoded into a JWT as described. Auth0 actually mentioned this in the liked post. Noone can really tamper with that unless they have the "app secret". If they have that, then it's probably game over anyways... Thanks for the resources!

Comment: Yeah I think what's maybe confusing about Intuit's example is it _shows plain text_, but the _comment says it should be inside a JWT_. Probably what they should be showing is _an actual JWT_, not just plain text.

Comment: @GustavHartz, why a JWT and not an encrypted string with the user and projectid?  I have a similar situation and the base64 payload seems easy to view userid and project.

Comment: @MatthewMichaud I think that is an equally good solution. I, unfortunately, don't remember why I did not just do that...